# Azure Storage Logs - How Unique Is RequestID?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to move the azure storage log file into azure storage tables so I can more easily work with them, but I noticed this

> "duplicate log records may exist in logs generated for the same hour
>   and can be detected by checking for duplicate RequestId and Operation
>   number."

source:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2011/08/02/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests/

(I know it's an old article, but it's all I can find)

With this in mind, I thought it would be sensible to use a concatenation of the requestID with the operationID as my row key.

I wanted to check if anyone is aware just *how* unique the requestID is (Apparently some requests might have more that 1 operation such as "copy", but most will have just 1).

If I'm using it as a row key, I can't afford for it to appear twice in the same partition (Partitioning by userID, but lets suppose each partition can contain millions of records).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I'm using it as a row key, I can't afford for it to appear twice in the same partition (Partitioning by userID, but lets suppose each partition can contain millions of records).

If I understand correctly, you could  combine requestID and new Guid with hyphenation as unique row key. for example: `requestId|newGuid`.